# Error Installing Visual Studio Ultimate

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation

When I want to install VS2010 Ultimate , I got some errors like this
"setup.exe has stopped working"
with the detail :

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   VSSetup
  Problem Signature 01: unknown
  Problem Signature 02: unknown
  Problem Signature 03: unknown
  Problem Signature 04: 1
  Problem Signature 05: engine_startup
  Problem Signature 06: Install_I_Interactive_Crash
  Problem Signature 07: 0xc0000006
  Problem Signature 08: unknown
  Problem Signature 09: unknown
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
  Locale ID:    1057

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

Sometimes I got other errors "suite integration toolkit executable has stopped working"

My OS is Windows 7 x64 SP1 Installed
Any help will be appreciate :)

Comment: That's a hard crash, caused by hardware problems.  The disk drive most likely.  Could be the optical drive if you install from a DVD.  You'll need to fix your machine first.

Comment: Honestly , I have been re-installing VS for many times for some reason.. FYI , i do not use dvd but virtual drive with the iso :D
anyway , thanks for the comments :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Step Uninstall Visual Basic using Add Remove Program in Control Panel, then use software Uninstaller (in my case , I'm  using "YourUninstaller", you can choose any software you want ) to clear the remaining trash registry.

Make sure that you have correctly install the .NET Framework 4.0 , and if you have Microsoft SQL Server please make sure that you install MS SQL Server first before installing the Visual Studio 2010

Comment: I have uninstall all related programs to VS but still I can't find the solution..
But thanks for the reply :)

Comment: i have another way for you, if the installer is having problem within ISO forms, better extract the ISO into a folder with WinRAR or any other software than can extract your ISO. after that , try running installation from the extracted folder.

Comment: Ok i have fixed the problem here using both of your solution , big thanks :D

Answer (score 4):

> FYI , i do not use dvd but virtual drive with the iso

That small comment is enormously relevant to the problem.  The exception code 0xc0000006 is STATUS_IN_PAGE_ERROR, a very low-level mishap that occurs when Windows tries to read data into RAM from a memory mapped file and an I/O error occurs that prevents the data from being read.  That's a fatal error when it happens for a .exe, like the setup.exe program, since it cannot execute code that can't be read.

Clearly whatever utility you use is borken, most likely because the driver it installs has a bug.  I'd strongly recommend you throw it away.  A workaround is to copy the content of the virtual disk to your hard drive and install from there.

Comment: A Big Help!
Really thanks for the appreciate , i've been clearly anything crash like update and etc..
Thanks to your comment @Hans Passant :)

Comment: This is the solutions that worked for me. thanks mate

Answer (score 1):

I uninstalled daemon tools and installed older version of daemon tools. I did the same step for installing visual studio ultimate and managed to install visual studio perfectly